# Allow only types from an interface as function arguments

Tags: typescript

I am creating a library for basic RPC. The library user defines functions simply in this way:

```
function func(arg1: string, arg2: number) { .... }

export const service = {
  func: func
}

export type Service = typeof service
```

However I would make sure that the functions the user defined do only accept JSON-compatible types (I do only care about compile time and to not care about runtime. I am only interested in good developer experience by making the linter complain if the function signature is not ok).

I ended up with this so far:

```
type JSONValue = string | number   // keep it simple for now
type RPCMethod<T extends JSONValue[]> = (...args: T) => JSONValue | void

function createRPCMethod<T extends JSONValue[]>(RPCMethod: RPCMethod<T>) {
    return RPCMethod
}

function f1(a: string) {}
function f2(a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: string) {}
function f3(a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: URL, e: Date) {}

const test1 = createRPCMethod(f1) // good
const test2 = createRPCMethod(f2) // good
const test3 = createRPCMethod(f3) // expected error, however weird error message
```

The error on test3 reads:

```
Argument of type '(a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: URL, e: Date) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RPCMethod<JSONValue[]>'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'JSONValue' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Why is it so weird and how can I get it to tell me that `d` should not be of the forbidden type `Date`?

I have a TS Playground example [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIDUCGAbArtAvFAOywFsAjCAJygB8oBnYCgSwIHMapSB7LjCNAgG4AUMNCQoAJQAKAYQCyEYAAsuAEwA8AFSgQAHsAgE1dWIlSYcAbQC6APij4AFADo3aCqzoAuKFoCUjg7wyOjY0LQAblxMaiLi0DIKSqpqCKQAVhAAxsCOUjlcFJoMzGwANFJyiirqGiEW4bZ2diLCAGZYBLlMXARQ2RT8hnCUkUzZEE5cvkk1qelZuYEA3sJQUEPAWBT9XMIAvqKd3cC9-YPDEHMpdTr6hsamDWHW9k43tWqz1beaWnZVsIAJBbHb9T6pQ7HLo9PpQdoARicaF8pRYrFWRxOcP67QATCi0YwMZVSL4iGRKJVsr5uLx%20ARKt96CS2FiOrCzvD2gBmImssqsMkUkjkCg0uk8PgCZm%20ACqkgAMpUIL4ACJoQwc4TZPoMKCGBiI-KXLXXX5fJxI-y6-V5I3AfGmobmyHqa34216ggGx28l1Xd1qa28wIAenDhuUTFMlAoRSgsd0ekguQgajJWAdymgxAgdDoaFY0GTAHcIExii5RD6DWhA%20bRhRxpMnCsEYjKgTuwGDv5BBtI7oKAmKKZvE5RMOAJJQMtcLAYNRQDBMADW0GAXHoTGIYD4ICgyjQkWgDZx3P6Ki1UDn2UwGHnTBUUAbdAxfDfnhIRmAlRUaAuEyHI8jLF9lARLlzlMG88mEYcTzPN9%20g8UgXwoNAjzQYhFwIdooC4AiwA8HDDHHZ9X34bJIJIzD83IzhKzYAYuDPIYV1II8XksCAa2nKM5zUHcCC4PICAgDNwzLAQ8goLoznzAZc2ydc6EqJh50XZdVw3PMjzXAhGO3Vj9wwNAWBcKAgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzDLRN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?